# Распарсить JSON и получить значение на PHP

Tags: php, json, парсер

Знаю, что нужно подучить получение массивов на PHP но время поджимает.
Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой JSON, хочу получить значение `price` по `id` например: 240439

Пример JSON:

```
[
 { "240438":[{"price":"100.00","name":"blabla1","loc":"center"}] },
 { "240439":[{"price":"100.00","name":"blabla2","loc":"center2"}] }
]
```

После декодинга:

```
 $PHP_arr= json_decode( $JSON_arr,true );
```

Пробую так получить значение:

```
echo $PHP_arr[240439][0]->price;
echo $PHP_arr[240439][0]->{'price'};
echo $PHP_arr[240439][0]['price']; //:))

введите сюда код
```

Где я туплю? Как получить `price` значение зная `id`?

Comment: Фигурная скобка - это объект в PHP (object или stdClass), квадратная - массив. Следовательно у вас это $EVariant_arr[0]->{240439}[0]->price

Answer (score 3):

У вас по структуре JSON есть массив объектов такого плана:

```
{ "240438":[{"price":"100.00","name":"blabla1","loc":"center"}] }
```

Соответственно получить информацию сразу по `id` не получится. Нужно сначала найти, где этот `id` находится. Например, для `id`, равного `240439`, цену можно получить так:

```
echo $PHP_arr[1]['240439'][0]['price'];
```

Соответственно, если известен только `id`, нужно выполнить поиск по массиву. Например, так:

```
$id = '240439';
foreach($PHP_arr as $value){
    if(array_key_exists($id, $value)){
        $price = $value[$id][0]['price'];
        break;
    }
}
echo $price;
```

Comment: Жаль не могу бал поставить (впервые тут), точно подмечено спасибо! Работает!

Comment: Нужно набрать рейтинг сайт пишет))